# Prove $\exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{2c}\right) < \sqrt{c} \exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{3c}\right)$ for $c > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Can someone please tell me how to prove the following inequality?

$$\exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{2c}\right) < \sqrt{c} \exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{3c}\right), \qquad c > 0, x \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Thanks.

Comment: Taking logarithm of both sides gives $-\frac{x^2}{2c} < \frac12 \log c - \frac{x^2}{3c} \implies 3c\log c+x^2 > 0$, so this can't be proved unless you put restrictions on $c$ and/or $x$.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality doesn't make sense for $c\leq 0$, so we assume $c \in \mathbb{R}^{>0}$.  When $x=0$ the inequality is true when $1<\sqrt{c}$ (and $c>0$), that is when $c>1$.  Now assume $x \neq 0$.

We take the right-hand side and divide by the left-hand side (which is non-zero), and observe that $$\sqrt{c}\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{3c}\right)}{\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2c}\right)}=\sqrt{c}\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2c}-\frac{x^2}{3c}\right)=\sqrt{c}\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{6c}\right)=\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{6c}+\log\sqrt{c}\right).$$

So the inequality is true provided that $$\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{6c}+\log\sqrt{c}\right)>1,$$ or equivalently $$x^2>-6c\log\sqrt{c}$$ since $x^2,c \in \mathbb{R}^{>0}$.  (Note that if $x=0$ and $c>1$, then the above equality is also true.)

So the given inequality holds for all $c \in \mathbb{R}^{>0}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ provided $x^2>-6c\log\sqrt{c}$.

Comment: I suspect there might be other constraints.  For any $x$ there will be $c$-values for which the inequality holds, and others for which it does not hold.  Seems unnatural.